# Spring DI Error when JUnit tests executed from Jar (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I want to create an executable jar for JUnit test cases built using Maven and Spring IoC (Dependency Injection).

The class containing the test also has following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})

public static void main(String[] args){
    JUnitCore.main("path/to/thisclass");
}
```

The tests run fine by right-clicking on the class containing the test however, I start seeing issues when I create a JAR in IntelliJ using (File > Project structure) and run the jar file. I see following errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testWrapper': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.voyanta.pages.TestWrapper.init(TestWrapper.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 63 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

I was wondering if anybody else seen this or resolved the issue above?

Comment: null pointer error occur in TestWrapper.java class at line number 40 so please share `TestWrapper.java:` class  for checking the issue.

Comment: AWESOME !!! Thanks a lot Mayank for your help, it worked. Line 40 had code which was getting System.getProperty("testService") and was blowing up. I just wanted to check if there is a way for me to access properties from Maven POM.XML when executing JUnit / Spring DI Maven test from executable jar?

Comment: ok, if you get another error please share with me

Comment: Thanks once again Mayank. I mean it's not a error - I actually commented out the values I was getting from the POM.XML and it started to work. My query was if there is a way to access property values from POM.XML when running JUNIT + Spring tests from an executable jar?